# How to display dynamically added form elements in a table in a different webpage when the data is saved in local storage using purely javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a school project in which I'm creating webpages to allow users to input and then display it on another page. I am only using javascript, html and css for the webpages. 
On the Create An Event page is a form. I have saved all the input into local storage but now I am unsure on how to retrieve the data to display in on another page called Event History. Here are my codes:

```
function saveToStorage() {
 var nameofevent=document.getElementById("name").value;
 var pList=document.getElementsByName("pos");
 var positions=[];

 for (i=0; i<pList.length; i++){
 positions.push(pList[i].value);
 console.log(pList[i].value);
 }

 //for (i=0; i<positions.length; i++){
 //console.log(positions[i].value);
 //}

 var venue= document.getElementById("venue").value;
 var date=document.getElementById("date").value;
 var starttime=document.getElementById("timeStart").value;
 var endtime=document.getElementById("timeEnd").value;
 var contact=document.getElementById("contact").value;
 var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
 var desc=document.getElementById("desc").value;

 var one={"name":nameofevent,"pos":positions,"venue":venue,"date":date,"timeStart":starttime,"timeEnd":endtime,"contact":contact,"email":email,"desc":desc};
 localStorage["CreateEvent"]=JSON.stringify(one);


 return false;
```

}

Whenever the user submits the Create An Event form, the data that the user inputs will be displayed in a table in another page. Here are my codes for the table:

```
<h1>Events Created</h1>
 <table border="1px" id="tab">
     <thead>
         <tr style=" font-size: 30px">
             <th id="event">Name of event</th>
             <th>Positions</th>
             <th id="">Venue</th>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>Start Time</th>
             <th>End Time</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>eg. Name</td>
             <td>eg. Position1, position2</td>
             <td>eg. venue</td>
             <td>eg. date</td>
             <td>eg. start time</td>
             <td>eg. end time</td>
         </tr>

     </tbody>
```

Comment: Yourstore=localStorage.getItem("createEvent");

Answer (score 1):

```
var saved=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("createEvent"));
alert(saved.name);
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read from the localStorage in the same way, you wrote to it.

You could add this function to your js:

```
function loadEvents() {
  //get the JSON Object from local storage
  var event = JSON.parse(localStorage["CreateEvent"]);
  //get the first row in the table
  var firstRow = document.querySelector('table tbody tr');
  //get the single tds
  var eventName = firstRow.querySelector('td:nth-child(1)');
  //put the data into the tds
  eventName.innerHTML = event.name;
}
```

Call this function with `<body onLoad="loadEvents()"`in your View Events page.
Make sure you add the `<script />` to the file.

This way it is very cumbersome to select the child nodes, so maybe you would want to put some classes in your markup.